# POST XML data to server via proxy in Python

Tags: python, http, xml-rpc, httplib, httplib2

I need to send a request that contains the data in the following format:

```
parameterss = urlencode({'various': 'credentials', ... ,
'xmlquery': '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> \
         <query>...</query>'})
```

Generally, it contains an XML query. Suppose the server I want it to send is `https://some/server` and my proxy is `proxy:port_number` . I tried to use `httplib2` with `SocksiPy` in the following way:

```
import httplib2, socks
from urllib import urlencode
proxy = httplib2.ProxyInfo(proxy_type=socks.PROXY_TYPE_HTTP, proxy_host='proxy', proxy_port=port_number)
http = httplib2.Http(proxy_info=proxy)
response, content = http.request("https://some/server", "POST", parameters)
print response
```

and it works but the response is not the desired one. Obviously because I need to use HTTPS proxy (which is the same). I don't have any certificate information - similar working Perl script doesn't use one, it defines proxies as Environment variables. `SocksiPy` has `PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS4` and `PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5` constants however, I don't know how to use those (without defining certificate it throws exceptions). Please point me on how to do this.

Maybe it will be appropriate to use `httplib` with `xmlrpclib`? How to define those and put together to work?

Comment: What kind of proxy do you use? Are you sure your proxy doesn't require any authentication? What's the output of the code you gave?

Comment: I don't know the proxy type, just address. I know that it works for both http and https. It doesn't require any authentication. The output should be an answer to the query (since the XML is translated to SQL on the server) but I get nothing. I don't have access to server in order to see what it actually gets.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured out the way and would like to share. It was much simpler than expected:

```
    import urllib, urllib2
    parameters = urllib.urlencode({'various': 'credentials', ... ,
    'xmlquery': '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> \
     <query>...</query>'})
    request = urllib2.Request("https://some/server", parameters)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    print response
```

I don't know why but it worked without defining any proxy in the code - I just defined it on the server via environment variables in the shell.